# How to resolve the dependencies in the java project which is imported through maven in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have imported multiple projects in eclipse through maven. After importing the projects in eclipse I saw that there are some error on the project folder in project explorer. All that errors are on pom.xml.

When I opened pom.xml the error is like this:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.openhie.openempi:openempi:pom:2.2.5 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

How to resolve this errors in eclipse? I tried a lot by adding the missing JAR's as specified in error message sometime, but still the errors are highlighting on pom.xml.

Please advice me for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a maven plugin that does that. You have to go with the command line at the root of your maven project and type

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

It will create (or update) an eclipse project with dependencies to the `jar` located in your local maven repository, and the eclipse project artifacts (.project, .classpath and other stuff) in the same repository.

Then import your project in eclipse using "Import existing project" wizard.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html for more information

Comment: @ Samuel: DO I need to use this command in command prompt or in eclipse? If in eclipse then how should I do that?

Comment: My answer was a bit short, I added more details about this tool.

Comment: mvn eclipse:eclipse is old school. Use m2e, as suggested in the other answer, and changes to the maven pom will always be reflected in your eclipse project.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Last time I used it had awfull lot of bugs, but indeed that was 4 years ago. Is it working now ?... And besides i'm old scool ;=)

Comment: @SamuelRossille yes, it used to be very buggy, but that was back when it was called m2eclipse. It's been very stable for at least two years, and it's now a core eclipse project with first-class integration

Comment: Ok, good news. I'll think about it on my next java project (I'm hacking C# at the moment)

Comment: I use the mvn eclipse:eclipse command and later I Import the project. But as I import the project I am not able to generate WAR file.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to generate WAR file". Were are you ? Are you speaking about the "File -> Export -> War" feature of eclipse or the maven build ? What is the problem ?

Comment: Also, it appears that ollins has provided a better solution, so you should probably use his solution.

Comment: Now I had a chance to use m2e on a new project and I confirm that it's really a much better process than mvn eclipse:eclipse

Answer (score 6):

Install http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/ via the eclipse marketplace. The plugin adds a

classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"

entry in the .classpath file for eclipse and every jar from the maven dependencies will be in your classpath.

Comment: After installing how should I import using m2e? is it used by default at the time of maven import?

Comment: two possibilities: import "existing maven projects" or if the project is already in your workspace, use right click at the project and "Configure" -> "Convert to Maven Project"

Comment: After installing m2e in eclipse, I observed that in classpath variables, there is a variable namely M2_REPO which is pointing to C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository. But you said that it should point to org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER. Also I didn't see the option  "Convert to Maven Project" under Configure. So I import it again from scrtach and again I am seeing errors on the same projects which I talked about about previously.

Comment: - remove the project from your workspace (Delete)
- remove the .settings directory, the .project and .classpath file
- Reimport via "Import" -> "Existing Maven Project"

If you don't have this menu entry the m2e eclipse plugin is not correct installed.

Comment: I have installed from eclipse market place and I saw 2 software for maven and I installed both of them.